# Python: Find the distance between two elements in 3D Numpy array respecting a condition

Tags: python, numpy, distance

I have a cubic 3D numpy array that corresponds to a 3D image of a body. It's binarized: 1 inside the body, 0 outside.
I want to find a distance map: Every element of my array must be substituted with the distance from the external surface (it means the first neighbor element with value == 0 ). 
So: How to find the distance between two elements in 3D Numpy array respecting a condition (different values of the two elements, 1 and 0) ?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html

Comment: you are right!! thanks

Comment: @dan-man you should post your comment as an answer